# Sql in java throws that java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "Row Number": invalid identifier, but run in PLSQL success

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

This problem just occurs in windows 8.1 with oracle 11.0.1.0, but in ubuntu and oracle 11.0.2.0 dose not happened.

Running select * from T_5188881_8 order by "Row_Number" in PLSQL success.
but in java code:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(String.format(
     "select * from %s order by \"Row_Number\"", tableNames.get(i)));
```

the tableNames.get(i) equals T_5188881_8, ...

the error info:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "Row_Number": invalid identifier

at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:207)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:790)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1039)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CStatement.java:830)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1132)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1272)
at partfinder.utils.SearchByPN.getResult(SearchByPN.java:180)
at partfinder.utils.SearchByPN.FuzzySearch(SearchByPN.java:116)
at partfinder.servlet.SearchPNServlet.doPost(SearchPNServlet.java:34)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2407)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2396)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: maybe a bug in `oracle 11.0.1.0`?

Comment: row_number is for transact SQL (MS SQLServer/Sybase). For Oracle it's rownum. Sure it works on Oracle SQL with "Row_number" ?

Comment: Does the column `Row_Number` in table

Comment: If the column Row_Number actually exists in your table, is its name Row_Number or "Row_Number" ?